# Facebook graph API add like to post

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I'm trying to like a post by its ID using Facebook API JavaScript I use the following script

```
 FB.api(
        "/me/og.likes",
        "POST",
        {
            "object": 'https://graph.facebook.com/'+idPagePost
        },
        function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            console.log("sucesssss");
            if (response && !response.error) {
                /* handle the result */
                console.log(response);
            }
        }
    );

});
```

I change the object by this one too `https://www.facebook.com/Hometalk/posts/1924476427569904` and it still not working
I have a success response like this below

```
Object {id: "1505224042835342"}
```

which is the id of the object like
but there is no like added with my name in this post

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: `og.likes` is for external Open Graph objects. You can not use it with internal objects such as pages, posts etc. _on_ Facebook.

Comment: thanks for your quick response.. there is any solution to handle this problem.. to like facebook posts by there id using JavaScript or laravel

Comment: what about this code::                                                                   
          FB.api('/'+ idPagePost +'/likes', 'post', function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (!response || response.error) {
                alert('Error occured. ID: ' + idPost);
            } else {
                alert('Great! It worked. ID: ' + idPost);

            }
        });

Comment: and i always get this response "(#3) Publishing likes through the API is only available for page access tokens"

Answer (score 0):

i find this message in [facebook graph api page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/object/likes#publish): 
*Note: as of Nov 17, 2016 we changed the behavior of publishing likes and only support this action with Page Access Tokens.*